# Unable to connect to my ASP.NET Core Web API after dockerization

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to dockerize my API and when I run it in VS Code locally it's working fine, but after dockerizing, I was unable to connect to the API.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./
RUN dotnet restore 
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o outBuildFolder

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /app1

ENV DOTNET_URLS=http://+:80

COPY --from=build-env /app/outBuildFolder/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","ShelfAPI.dll"]
```

This is the section of my docker-compose file:

```
shelfapi:
    build: ./ShelfAPI
    ports:
      - "4040:80"
    secrets:
      - my_secret
    networks:
      - betterreads
```

This is the simple function I am trying to test with:

```
[HttpGet("Test")]
public bool TestCon()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I've made it");
    return true;
}
```

I tried going into the docker exec tab in docker desktop running the curl command

```
curl http://localhost:80/ShelfCtrl/Test
```

I have also tried connecting from localhost and an emulator and get unable to connect screen or a time out.
I get nothing, instead of the true and my docker container now looks like this.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
2023-10-30 15:32:55       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4040/ShelfCtrl/Test - -
2023-10-30 15:32:55 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
2023-10-30 15:32:55       Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4040/ShelfCtrl/Test - - - 307 0 - 0.9282ms
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: have you tried from outside. with port 4040 as you mention in docker compose

Comment: I've added more information as well as what happens when connecting